# how does the basis of an inner product space change when the domain is deformed

Tags: fourier-analysis, sp.spectral-theory

Assume we have a complete orthogonal system on a domain $D$, given by the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian on $D$.  For example, the set $\{e^{int}\}$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$, or the spherical harmonics on the unit ball.  Now consider a domain $D'$, which is "close" to D in some sense (the boundary of $D$ is close to the boundary of $D'$ in some suitable norm).

Are the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian on $D$ close, in some sense, to the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian on $D'$?  Does knowing the basis of $D$ help approximate the basis of $D'$ ?  Any known results along these or similar lines appreciated.

Comment: This is touching on something interesting, but I think you need to be more precise, because there is no such thing as *the* basis for $L^2(D')$. It seems like you have some preferred basis in mind, but if so you need to pose your question more precisely

Comment: What do you mean by L^2 distances between boundaries of domains?

Comment: I think fredjalves is thinking about the preferred basis for L^2(D) and L^2(D') from eigenfunctions of the Laplacian.  At least that's what the two examples suggest.

Comment: good point Yemon and jc.  Yes, I was thinking of the basis from eigenfunctions of the Laplacian, not just any basis.

Jonas: assuming $D$ and $D'$ are subsets of $R^n$, then their boundaries are functions on $R^{n-1}$.  I'd like to say that those boundaries are close, with respect to some suitable norm (different from the the norm induced by the inner product on $R^n$)

Answer (score 2):

The study of eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the Laplacian is a well-developed field called [spectral geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_geometry).  You might start with the first few lectures in the course notes [here](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~saito/courses/LapEig/) or the book by Craioveanu et al. "Old and new aspects in spectral geometry".

Perhaps some experts can point you to better introductory references.